# Rails Devise fields_for not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, devise, formula, fields-for

I am using Devise, but I don't think this is of much importance right here.

I simply don't see the fields_for being created.

These are my files:

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, html: { id: 'registration_form', class: '' }, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

  <!-- Error messages -->
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <%= render 'new_user_fields', f: f %>

    <!-- Fields for user-information -->
    <%= f.fields_for :user_info do |f| %>

      <%= render 'shared/user_info_fields_for_sign_up', f: f, resource: resource %>

    <% end %>

    <!-- Fields for driver-information -->
    <%= f.fields_for :driver do |f| %>

      <%= render 'shared/driver_fields_for_sign_up', f: f, resource: resource %>

    <% end unless resource.driver.nil? %>

  <!-- Submit button -->
  <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "" %>

<% end %>
```

**shared/_user_info_fields_for_sign_up.html.erb**

```
<%= f.label t :label_gender %>
<%= f.collection_select :gender_id, Gender.all, :id, :type, class: '' %>

<%= f.label t :label_first_name %>
<%= f.text_field :first_name, class: "" %>

<%= f.label t :label_last_name %>
<%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "" %>

<%= f.label t :label_year_of_birth %>
<%= f.text_field :year_of_birth, class: "" %>

<%= f.label t :label_country %>
<%= f.select :country_alpha2, options_for_select: { Country.all }, class: '' %>

<%= f.label t :label_city %>
<%= f.text_field :city, class: "" %>

<%= f.fields_for :languageskills do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/languageskill_fields', f: f %>

<% end unless resource.user_info.languageskills.empty?%>

<%= link_to_add_fields t :label_add_language, f, :languageskills %>

<%= f.label t :label_interests %>
<%= f.text_field :interests, class: "" %>

<%= f.label t :label_about %>
<%= f.text_field :about, class: "" %>
```

**RegistratiosController.rb**

```
def new
    super
    resource.build_user_info
    resource.user_info.languageskills.build
    if params[:is_driver].to_i == 1
      resource.build_driver
    end
    Rails.logger.debug(resource.build_user_info.inspect)
end
```

**Console.log**

```
Started GET "/en/sign_up?is_driver=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-13 13:20:01 +0100
Processing by RegistrationsController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"is_driver"=>"1", "locale"=>"en"}
  Rendered registrations/_new_user_fields.html.erb (12.1ms)
  Rendered registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (27.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
#<UserInfo id: nil, user_id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, year_of_birth: nil, city: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, gender_id: nil, interests: nil, about: nil, country_alpha2: nil>
Completed 200 OK in 117ms (Views: 96.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

The `_new_user_fields.html.erb` are being loaded without any problems.
I've inserted all possible symbols to the input params of devise in the `application_controller.rb`. Though that doesn't matter, right?

Could you point me into the right direction? I don't see my fault :S

Answer (score 0):

Just found the source of the bug and will open a new post for it.

I could not call

```
resource.build_nested_model
```

in my controller. But when I call it in the view, it works. The nested model seems to be not saved into the resource, when it's passed to the view.

**Link to the new thread**

[Rails Devise Build nested model in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765482/rails-devise-build-nested-model-in-controller)