# Rails Devise Build nested model in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller

I'm using `Devise` and am trying to build nested models in my `RegistrationsController`.

Though this is not working. I can build nested models via

```
resource.build_nested_model
```

in the view, but not in the controller itself.

This is my **registrationscontrollers' new-action**

```
  def new
    super
    resource.build_user_info
    resource.user_info.languageskills.build
    if params[:is_driver].to_i == 1
      resource.build_driver
    end
    Rails.logger.debug(resource.build_user_info.inspect)
  end
```

This is the **output** it generates:

```
Started GET "/en/sign_up?is_driver=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-13 13:20:01 +0100
Processing by RegistrationsController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"is_driver"=>"1", "locale"=>"en"}
  Rendered registrations/_new_user_fields.html.erb (12.1ms)
  Rendered registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (27.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
#<UserInfo id: nil, user_id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, year_of_birth: nil, city: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, gender_id: nil, interests: nil, about: nil, country_alpha2: nil>
Completed 200 OK in 117ms (Views: 96.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Why is it not possible? I guess devise isn't saving my changes to the resource, when I build the associated models. The only way out I see is defining my own variable holding a whole copy of the updated resource. This is not a good practice, though.

What would you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the default `RegistrationsController.new` is just:

```
def new
  build_resource({})
  respond_with self.resource
end
```

(It depends on your version of devise, but it seems to be this or equivalent for quite a long way back.)

This means that the view is rendered (by `respond_with`) before you add your nested models in your overridden `new` because you do this after calling `super`.  I think you have two options:

1. Don't call `super`.  Just put the first line from the default `new` at the start of your `new`, and the last line from the default `new` at the end of yours.
2. Override `build_resource` instead of `new`.  At the beginning of your overridden `build_resource`, call `super` and then add the code that was in your `new` after the `super` in your `build_resource`.  The only extra thing you'll need to do is check whether `build_resource` was called with `nil` or an empty hash, in which case you build your blank user_info etc., or if it was called with a non-empty hash then don't add your blank user_info etc., because `build_resource` must have been called from `create`, so the hash will contain whatever your user entered on the form for user_info, so you don't want to overwrite with a blank version! (you could perhaps check the current url or something like that instead of checking the hash parameter, but I personally like that a little less.)

I have used option 2 in the past.  I like it because it still calls `super`, so we're still using devise's implementation of `build_resource`, whereas option 1 completely ignores devise's implementation of `new` -- and what if they make some important change to their `new` in future which you are then missing out on?  (For example, there used to be a `resource` variable local to `new`, but it's now on `self` as you can see in the code above.)  Option 2 is just a bit more fiddly because you need to check whether you should add your blank user_info etc.  So it's up to your taste!